# How to pull 'one to many' relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Postgres using dBeaver or SQLDeveloper.

I need help with the logic on this.

I have the following data

| rule_id | primary_component | secondary_component |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500430 | R0558 |  |
| 500430 | R0477 |  |
| 500430 | Q6457 |  |
| 500430 |  | Q2501 |
| 500430 |  | Q2502 |
| 500430 |  | Q2503 |

And I need to pull the data in this manner:

| rule_id | primary_component | secondary_component |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500430 | R0558 | Q2501 |
| 500430 | R0558 | Q2502 |
| 500430 | R0558 | Q2503 |
| 500430 | R0477 | Q2501 |
| 500430 | R0477 | Q2502 |
| 500430 | R0477 | Q2503 |
| 500430 | Q6457 | Q2501 |
| 500430 | Q6457 | Q2502 |
| 500430 | Q6457 | Q2503 |

I can't seem to manage it with the GROUP BY function.

Answer (score 0):

use join with filtered subqueries:

```
select t1.rule_id, primary_component, secondary_component 
from (
    select rule_id, primary_component
    from tablename 
    where secondary_component is null
) t1 
join (
    select rule_id , secondary_component
    from tablename 
    where primary_component is null
) t2 on t1. rule_id = t2. rule_id
```